# No mnemonic-seed was used with initial installation of Monero GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed

No mnemonic-seed was used with initial installation and synchronization of Monero GUI wallet.

Is there anyway to use a 25 word mnemonic-seed after the wallet finishes the synchronizing process to aid in wallet restoration?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When making the wallet for first time, it will generate a 25 word seed. (save of course). Then if stuff happens, you can use that seed to restore the wallet or just to put on another 'puter.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I had just discovered this and was back to post that I discovered this; your answer. Under settings. As you can see newbie@!

Comment: This question is answered.